# PHP form, drop down list & mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having a form to insert the books details in my database. I am having 4 tables in my database 1)ssc_eng 2)ssc_hindi 3)ssc_urdu 4) ssc_marathi. In my insert_book form their is a drop down list which have these above tables. If admin select one of these tables from the drop down list then all the data which is inserted by admin in insert_book form should be inserted in selected drop down item which is the table in my database. So, I am tying but not getting the logic. Example: if admin select "ssc_eng" in drop down list then all the data from the form should have to be inserted in "ssc_eng" table in my database.

SUMMARY QUESTION:

```
Use drop down list to insert form data to the selected database of the drop down list



<?php 
  include("includes/connect.php"); 

     if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
    {
     echo "<script>window.open('login.php?not_admin=You are not an     Admin!','_self')</script>";
    }
    else
    {

     ?>

<html>
<head>

<title> Product Insert Page</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#414141">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <form method="post" action="insert_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <table align="center" width="700" height="800" border="2" bgcolor="#5E0000">

  <tr align="center">
  <td colspan="7" style="padding-top: 10px; font-size:20px; font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; color:#EEEEEE"><h2>Insert Books</h2></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Book Title:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_title" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Language:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background: #B6B6B6;">
  <select name="b_language" required/>
  <option>Select Language</option>
  <?php
   $cat_query= "select * from categories";
   $query_runs= mysqli_query($con, $cat_query);
   while($row_cat=mysqli_fetch_array($query_runs))
 {
   $cat_id=$row_cat['cat_id'];
   $cat_title=$row_cat['cat_title'];
   echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
}
?>
  </select>
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Standard(Class):</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;">
  <select name="b_class" required/>
  <option> Select Standard </option>
  <?php
  $brd_query="select  * from brands";
  $run_query=mysqli_query($con, $brd_query);
  while($row_brd=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query))
 {
  $brand_id=$row_brd['brand_id'];
  $brand_title=$row_brd['brand_title'];
  echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
 }
 ?>
 </select>
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Book Image:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="file" name="b_image" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Author Name:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_author" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Publish Year:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_publish" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Book Price:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_price" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Book Description:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;">
  <textarea name="b_desc" cols="20" rows="10" required></textarea>
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>No. of Pages:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_pages" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Stock(In/Out):</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;">
  <select name="b_stock" required/>
  <option> Stock In </option>
  <option> Stock Out </option>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Delivery within(in days)</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;">
  <select name="b_delivery" required/>
  <option> 6 </option>
  <option> 7 </option>
  <option> 8 </option>
  <option> 9 </option>
  <option> 10 </option>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Delivery Charges:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_deliverychar" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td align="right" style="font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro', 'Times New Roman'; font-size:20px; padding-right: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><b>Book Keywords:</b></td>
  <td style="padding-left: 16px; background:#B6B6B6;"><input type="text" name="b_keywords" size="30" required/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
  <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert Book Now"  class="btn btn-primary"/></td>
  </tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['insert_post']))
{
// getting the text fields from form
 $b_title = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_title']);
 $b_language = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_language']);
 $b_class = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_class']);
 $b_author = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_author']);
 $b_publish = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#', '', $_POST['b_publish']);
 $b_price = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['b_price']);
 $b_desc = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_desc']);
 $b_pages = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['b_pages']);;
 $b_stock = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_stock']);
 $b_delivery = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#', '', $_POST['b_delivery']);
 $b_deliverychar = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['b_deliverychar']);
 $b_keywords = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['b_keywords']);

 //getting image data from the form
 $b_image = $_FILES['b_image']['name'];
 $b_image_tmp = $_FILES['b_image']['tmp_name'];

 move_uploaded_file($b_image_tmp,"books_images/$b_image");

 $insert_books=  "insert into products (product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_keywords) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";

 $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_books) or die(mysqli_error($con));

 if($insert_pro)
 {
  echo "<script>alert('Book is sucessfully added!')</script>"; 
  echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_product','_self')</script>"; 
 }

}

?>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am having more queries any body who can solve plz it is urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling it to insert into the products table, so if you want it to go into the ssc_eng table then you'll have to check which select option is present ($b_class) and substitute that in place of "products"

Comment: drop down list is dynamic list & if i add tables in my database then drop down list is all having that new tables names. i have a separate php program for this drop down list as categories.php

Comment: I'm failing to see the problem. If your dropdown list is based on the tables that exist, then when you go to do your insert and you substitute in the name of the table, it will work because that table exists. 

IE: "Insert INTO $b_class (...".

Comment: can u please provide me the insert query for the problem . I am new  to the mysql & php & dont know much about these languages

Comment: You already have the query, you just need to change the name of the table you're inserting to like I pointed out above.

Comment: Okzz so i have to just remove "products" from the insert query & add "$b_class". I will try this & get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I had created a different table as "HSC_eng" and this table have different values, so how would i add the form content into the "HSC_eng" table which is having different fields as compared to "ssc_eng" table.